# how to restart a job in coroutine?

Tags: android

I use a coroutine for recording using audiorecord. After I use start and stop and start the job, the job don't start anything. Is there no way to restart a job? I wanna start->stop->start because it's recording. here is my code. At first, my app start recording, and when I click the record button, then the job is cancelled. But when I click recording button again, the job doesn't start.

*onCreate*

```
 scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
        job =scope.launch {
            val readData = ByteArray(mBufferSize)
            mFilePath = getExternalTempFileDirectory(this@AudioRecorderActivity)+"/audiorecord.pcm"
            var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
            try {
                fos = FileOutputStream(mFilePath)
            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            while (isRecording) {
                val ret = mAudioRecord!!.read(readData, 0, mBufferSize)
                Log.d(TAG, "read bytes is $ret")
                try {
                    fos!!.write(readData, 0, mBufferSize)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            mAudioRecord!!.stop()
            mAudioRecord!!.release()
            mAudioRecord = null
            try {
                fos?.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

*record function*

```
   fun onRecord() {
        if (isRecording == true) {
            isRecording = false
            job.cancel()
            binding.recordStartButton!!.text = "Record"

        } else {
            isRecording = true
            job.start()
            binding.recordStartButton!!.text = "Stop"
            if (mAudioRecord == null) {
                mAudioRecord = AudioRecord(mAudioSource, mSampleRate, mChannelCount, mAudioFormat, mBufferSize)
                mAudioRecord!!.startRecording()
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Jobs are not recoverable once canceled, you have to start a new one. You should also be using `SupervisorScope` instead because otherwise cancellation is propagated "upwards" which causes scope that hosted your canceled job to become canceled as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin Coroutines, a cancelled job cannot be restarted . You need to create a new job.